# Generate valid Authorization:Basic

Tags: java, network-programming, authorization

I'm trying to generate correct string for Authorization:Basic [string] but i fail because i'm not really sure what info should i encode.
First request that client sends is sign_up request which doesn't include Authorization.Response for that request looks like this:

```
{
"user": {
    "name": "Genome",
    "id": 2417370297
},
"identifier": "OFpDN0VJU3UxM1B1dTZTWDNMS1hqYWNwbmFjM3Zib0lBaTJYbTdUUWVWRkhTUUdYVWJyK0FobnppY1pkZEFwTG1OQkpoQjBGOVY5RmVtN0RtQ1BsUEE9PTpZaTc1SFZBeDFsWGxZaUZNeDZxTTZRPT0="
}
```

After that,the next request client should send is sign_in which includes Authroization:Basic.This is how Authorization looks:

```
Authorization: Basic WWk3NUhWQXgxbFhsWWlGTXg2cU02UT09OjhaQzdFSVN1MTNQdXU2U1gzTEtYamFjcG5hYzN2Ym9JQWkyWG03VFFlVkZIU1FHWFVicitBaG56aWNaZGRBcExtTkJKaEIwRjlWOUZlbTdEbUNQbFBBPT0=
```

Problem is i don't know how to generate that string after "Basic" .If you need any info ask here

Comment: Seems like very bad security implementation. 1. No any user information must available without authorization.2. password must be provided by user and only by user. 3. Basic authorization means actually open password sends over network. Even when it is internal Network it is a bad approach.

Comment: I'm just trying to reverse-engineer all requests that client (a game called DokkanBattle) sends to the server.I didn't code the game and i didn't code the server

Comment: Understood. Still password can be provided by user and only by user. If you do not have it - you don't. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication is name:password encoded in Base64.

Comment: Well i don't have those .I only got name,id and identifier